Designing transfer function compensator to create a stable response
I am working on create a control system to control a satellite to be fixed with respect to a distant start (theoretically). The transfer function of the dynamic model of the system is shown below in my MATLAB script and command window. The parameter values have been chosen appropriately and should not be a problem. I am working on create a response with less than 15% overshoot, settling time less than 20 seconds, and zero steady state error. The problem I am running into is that the response of my system in unstable. And I cant quite figure out how to fix it.
Heres what I'm doing and what isn't working. a damping ratio of roughly 0.5 or higher would result in percent overshoot less than 15%. I created the root locus plot of my system on matlab along with 5 lines of constant zeta ranging from 0.5 - 1. I inputted the functionality so that when the root locus plot appears, I can choose a point on the root locus that intercepts one of the lines of constant zeta (I have experimented with them all). Then the gain from that design point is used and applied to the original transfer function to plot its response. And the response keeps ending up unstable. I have a trong feeling this is because the original transfer function has two poles at the origin, and I feel that some sort of compensator can fix that, but Im not sure how. Because any compesator I look into doesn't deal with removing poles from the origin, and all the textbook examples seem to apply compensators to already stable systems. See the picture below. Let me know if you have any suggestions.




You can't "remove" poles, but you can move their closed-loop placement. In general, poles are attracted to zeros and repelled by other poles. So add left-half-plane zeros to your compensator, which will attract the root locus (esp of those diagonal lines going right) into the left-half-plane. As a practical matter, it's typ. necessary to add pole/zero pairs, but that's okay as long as the pole (within the p/z pair) is further to the left and the zero is somewhere intermediate. There will be both an upper and lower limit of gain that will work. May have to compromise on measures of performance

Please edit the question so that the code is text which can be copied (and not screenshot of text).

It is not sufficient that some poles lie on the desired-zeta line; All other poles should be strictly on the left hand plane for that gain value (all other poles should probably be on higher zeta values unless lying very close to a zero). In your case, the two poles at origin never appear to land on LHS (strictly).

Since you are trying to stabilise a double integrator, you need more than a simple proportional feedback.
